# faster than in_array?

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

I need to compare a value to a set of array. However, I need to compare multiple values in foreach. If using in_array, it can be slow, real slow. Is there any faster alternative? My current code is

```
foreach($a as $b){
   in_array($b, $array);
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: define "real slow" in numbers please

Comment: Arrays are still the same in PHP5 as they were in PHP4, please tag correctly. http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`array_diff`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) to compute the difference between the `$a` array against `$array`. This would give you all the values not in `$array` or `$a`.

Example from Manual:

```
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue", "red");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
print_r( array_diff($array1, $array2) );

Array
(
    [1] => blue
)
```

Or you can use [`array_intersect`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) to find those that are in those arrays.

`array_intersect` Example from PHP Manual:

```
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
print_r( array_intersect($array1, $array2) );

Array
(
    [a] => green
    [0] => red
)
```

Pick the one you need.

Answer (score 3):

If you can treat the array as a hash:

```
$array = array('value' => 1);
```

Then in the foreach do this:

```
foreach($a as $b){
    isset($array[$b]);
}
```

I just copied&pasted your example, I suppose there is more code but basically using the [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) is a lot faster than using the in_array function,

Answer (score 1):

I think you are searching for the intersection of $a an $array, aren't you? If yes, simply use `array_intersect()`

Comment: I think you mean `array_intersect()`

Comment: @Dennis Haarbrink: Yes, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Implode the outer array with a delimiter that is forbidden to be written in the array value:

```
$x = "\x1a";
$array = $x . implode($x, $array) . $x;
foreach ($a as $b) {
    if (strpos($array, $x . $b . $x) !== false) {
        // in array
    }
}
```