# For large string of comma separated substrings, is foreach or in_array faster for checking?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I read this post: [faster than in_array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510180/faster-than-in-array) but I tried an experiment with a part of my php code. In my site's database users have stored a string (**$UserString** here) of comma-separated text substrings. I originally was checking if a user input (**$PostedVar**) was a member of the array created by exploding **$UserString** by using a foreach loop (I have recreated a small part of the relevant code here):

```
$PostedVar = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['userinput']);
$CommaCount = substr_count($UserString, ','); 
$ExplodedUserString = explode(",", $UserString);
$Break = 'nobreak';

$i = 1;  
foreach ($ExplodedUserString as $EUS) {
    $Current = $EUS;
    if ($i > $CommaCount) {
        break;
    }
    else if ($Current === $PostedVar) {
        $Break = 'break';
        break;
    }
    else {            
        $i++;
    }
}//End foreach

if ($Break === 'break') {
    echo "<script>
    alert ('You have previously selected "'.$PostedVar.'". Please try again!');
    location = 'home.php';
    </script>"        
}
else {
    echo "<script>
    alert ('Thanks for selecting "'.$PostedVar.'"!');
    location = 'home.php';
    </script>";
}
```

I then compared foreach vs. in_array to check **$UserString** by doing everything exactly the same except adding 2 microtime statements as follows for both foreach and in_array:

```
//foreach method
$time1 = microtime();
$i = 1;  
foreach ($ExplodedUserString as $EUS) {
    $Current = $EUS;
    if ($i > $CommaCount) {
        break;
    }
    else if ($Current === $PostedVar) {
        $Break = 'break';
        break;
    }
    else {

        $i++;
    }
}//End foreach

$time2 = microtime();
$Diff = $time2 - $time1;

if ($Break === 'break') {
    echo "<script>
    alert ('$Diff');
    location = 'home.php';
    </script>"        
}
else {
    echo "<script>
    alert ('$Diff');
    location = 'home.php';
    </script>";
}
```

versus:

```
//in_array method
$time1 = microtime();
if (in_array($PostedVar, $ExplodedUserString)) {
    $Break = 'break';
}
$time2 = microtime();
$Diff = $time2 - $time1;

if ($Break === 'break') {
    echo "<script>
    alert ('$Diff');
    location = 'home.php';
    </script>"        
}
else {
    echo "<script>
    alert ('$Diff');
    location = 'home.php';
    </script>";
}
```

I did 9 trials where all factors were kept constant (clicked same submit button, same user, same **$UserString**, etc.) and threw out the high and low values...the mean of **$Diff** with 7 trials for both foreach and in_array **was actually faster by 12% for in_array**. Keep in mind this is for a short string of only 5 comma-separated values for **$UserString**. Especially for larger strings, wouldn't in_array be faster than a foreach loop? The importance for my site is that I anticipate typical **$UserString** values to have at least 10-20 times more characters than the **$UserString** I used to test.

Comment: You might be able to answer this question yourself by using a bigger sample size. Comparing a (say) 10ms runtime to an 8ms run time gives a 20% improvement but the difference in speed is insignificant. Also, you haven't posted the timings of your tests. Run the tests on a string of 10k items and see what happens then - you'll get much more reliable results. Percentages don't mean anything out of context

Comment: OK...fair point. Unfortunately, I don't have 10k items to test right now. I suppose I can try to re-test for a much larger string.

Comment: Surely you can just generate a dummy string? You could take your existing test data and copy and paste it a few hundred times

Comment: One point to note: in_array does the same thing for my purposes as foreach in far fewer lines....for what this is worth!

Comment: Definitely....will do.

Comment: In that case, use the cleaner solution unless it gives a large, **noticable** delay in processing. If the difference is a few milliseconds, ignore it. "Premature optimisation is the root of all evil" - Donald Knuth `;)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're exploding in both scenarios, you might consider just exploding to a key value pair and doing a simple isset on the key you're looking for.  I can't say what the performance would be, and without having viewed PHP source, I'd say in_array probably do it's own foreach.

Just a link to consider:

[explode() into $key=>$value pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15966693/explode-into-key-value-pair)